# IOS : Unable to setup GCM using cordova plugin phonegap-plugin-push

Tags: ios, cordova, google-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I have set provisioning profiles, certificates and cocoapods by following:

https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client link.

I do not know whether I have to register in APNS through cocoapod or cordova plugin and how to do it. GCM is not registering through ios device. I would prefer to not use native code, I am new to both xcode and cordova.

Answer (score 0):

cocoapod is only the dependency management tool for Objective-C and Swift. So my guess is that you'll have to register it on  a Cordova plugin. I think this [pubnub tutorial](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2014-12-22-sending-ios-push-notifications-via-apns-javascript-using-apns-phonegap/) will be beneficial to on how to set it up using phonegap/cordova.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This is an older version of the plugin I am using, this one uses APNS to send notifications to ios, I want to use gcm on ios, but I need the app to regiser with APNS according to the google link, the google link has another link pointing to a process which is specific for native apps, but I need to replicate that on my hybrid app

Comment: Now I am getting Gcm reg id , i think it was Xcode bitcode setting issue in build settings, but still haven't figured out how to register with APNS

Comment: I was using testflight so only APNS production certificate could be used to get APNS regid,now i am using APNS to send notifications to the app still couldnt figure out how to make gcm on ios work with this plugin